# Call a method when courser is in text-area in vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, chat

i am new in vue js. i have a text-area  for chatting. when courser is in the text area how can i call a method.
here is my code:

```
<template>
<div class="composer">

<textarea v-model="Keijiban" @keydown.enter="send"  @click="selectContact(kokyaku1)" @keydown="selectContact(kokyaku1)" placeholder="ここにメッセージを入力してください。"></textarea>

</div>
</template>
```

this is my method

```
selectContact(kokyaku1) {
            this.$emit('readkorsi',kokyaku1);
        }
```

how can i call `"selectContact(kokyaku1)"` method  when courser is in `text-area`

Answer (score 2):

The `focus` event is triggered when the user selects the textinput and it gains focus.

The `blur` event is triggered when the user selects anywhere outside of the textarea and it loses focus (blurs).

Use the `focus` and blur `blur` events as needed. You may want to remove your `keydown` listener if you are already listening for the focus event.

```
<textarea @focus="selectContact(kokyaku1)" @blur="hideContact"></textarea>
```